UITableView remove padding cells
I want to completely paint the background of some cells with black. I do it like this.
cell.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

But this is what I get. How do I remove padding inside cells? I want a solid black fill between cells.


tableView.intercellSpacing = NSSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)


Why not NSZeroSize? Or CGSize.zero?
